# How do I validate the format of a MAC address?

Tags: python

What's the best way to validate that an MAC address entered by the user?

The format is `HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH`, where each `H` is a hexadecimal character.

For instance, `00:29:15:80:4E:4A` is valid while `00:29:804E4A` is invalid.

Comment: What is a valid MAC address for you? Just the structure? Or also e.g. that the vendor part is correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "valid"? Does it have to actually represent the hardware in your hand? Or your user's hand? Does it have to be from a hardware vendor? Or are MACs that are assigned by software vendors (perhaps a VPN or other networking contraption has been implemented using a software-only NIC) also okay? How would you maintain and update the list as new vendors come, and as existing vendors sell more NICs?

Comment: This is a example of valid structure: 00:29:15:80:4E:4A
This is a bad mac address: 00:29:804E4A

Comment: @Manu, count the colons? This is no "validation" anyway. :)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you mean just the syntax then this regexp should work for you

```
import re
...
if re.match("[0-9a-f]{2}([-:]?)[0-9a-f]{2}(\\1[0-9a-f]{2}){4}$", x.lower()):
    ...
```

it accepts 12 hex digits with either `:` or `-` or nothing as separators between pairs (but the separator must be uniform... either all separators are `:` or are all `-` or there is no separator).

This is the explanation:

- `[0-9a-f]` means an hexadecimal digit
- `{2}` means that we want two of them
- `[-:]?` means either a dash or a colon but optional. Note that the dash as **first** char doesn't mean a range but only means itself. This subexpression is enclosed in parenthesis so it can be reused later as a back reference.
- `[0-9a-f]{2}` is another pair of hexadecimal digits
- `\\1` this means that we want to match the same expression that we matched before as separator. This is what guarantees uniformity. Note that the regexp syntax is `\1` but I'm using a regular string so backslash must be escaped by doubling it.
- `[0-9a-f]{2}` another pair of hex digits
- `{4}` the previous parenthesized block must be repeated exactly 4 times, giving a total of 6 pairs of digits: `<pair> [<sep>] <pair> ( <same-sep> <pair> ) * 4`
- `$` The string must end right after them

Note that in Python `re.match` only checks starting at the start of the string and therefore a `^` at the beginning is not needed.

Comment: Don't forget a `$` at the end of the regular expression. Otherwise it'll match `'00:29:15:80:4E:4A:any random text here'` as well.

Comment: Perhaps it is worthwhile to update to `^[0-9a-f]{2}([-:]?)[0-9a-f]{2}(\\1[0-9a-f]{2}){4}$`.  I needed to include the case for no delimiter, and its a minor edit which follows the same logic as above but is more generic.  I also added a carat to provide the same logic as $ at the front

Comment: @jonathan: I've added the optionality of the separator. The caret at the beginning is not needed however because the code uses `match` and not `search`.

Comment: Wow, quick response.  Thank you, and point taken on `match` vs `search`.

Comment: [This doesn't cover EUI-64 format](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/f8d795820e780a6322e054c26c581570613c14f0/ext/filter/tests/055.phpt#L19) addresses, which look like `0123.4567.89ab`.

Answer (score 3):

I hate programs that force the user to think a like a computer.

Make it more friendly by accepting any valid format.

Strip the separator, whatever it is, then get the hex value that's left. That way if a user enters dashes or spaces it also works.

```
import string
allchars = "".join(chr(a) for a in range(256))
delchars = set(allchars) - set(string.hexdigits)

def checkMAC(s):
  mac = s.translate("".join(allchars),"".join(delchars))
  if len(mac) != 12:
      raise ValueError, "Ethernet MACs are always 12 hex characters, you entered %s" % mac 
  return mac.upper()


checkMAC("AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF")
checkMAC("00-11-22-33-44-66")
checkMAC("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c")
checkMAC("This is not a mac")
```

Comment: This code ignores all sort of characters, that's a bit too much... For a counter-example, it appears your code accepts `"For I have sworn the fair and thought the bright who art as"` as valid input.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure that there is either '-' or ':' throughout but not both, you can use following in Python:

```
import re

def is_valid_macaddr802(value):
    allowed = re.compile(r"""
                         (
                             ^([0-9A-F]{2}[-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})$
                            |^([0-9A-F]{2}[:]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})$
                         )
                         """,
                         re.VERBOSE|re.IGNORECASE)

    if allowed.match(value) is None:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: Combining `:` and `-` should be possible: `^([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})$`

Answer (score 1):

I cheated and used combination of multiple answers submitted by other people. I think this is pretty clear and straight forward one liner. `mac_validation` should return `True` or `False`.

```
import re
mac_validation = bool(re.match('^' + '[\:\-]'.join(['([0-9a-f]{2})']*6) + '$', mac_input.lower()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final String MAC_PATTERN = "^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$";

private boolean validateMAC(final String mac){          
          Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(MAC_PATTERN);
          Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mac);
          return matcher.matches();             
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dash-separated MAC addresses can also contain a '01-' prefix, which specifies it is an Ethernet MAC address (not token ring, for example ... who uses token ring?).

Here's something that is somewhat complete and easy to read in a logical step-through way:

```
def IsMac(S):
  digits = S.split(':')
  if len(digits) == 1:
    digits = S.split('-')
    if len(digits) == 7:
      if digits[0] != '01':
        return False
      digits.pop(0)
  if len(digits) != 6:
    return False
  for digit in digits:
    if len(digit) != 2:
      return False
    try:
      int(digit, 16)
    except ValueError:
      return False
  return True


for test in ('01-07-09-07-b4-ff-a7',  # True
                '07:09:07:b4:ff:a7',  # True
                '07-09-07-b4-GG-a7',  # False
                 '7-9-7-b4-F-a7',     # False
                 '7-9-7-b4-0xF-a7'):  # False
  print test, IsMac(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

def MacValidator(inputMacList):
    def MacParser(mac):
        octets = re.split('[\:\-]', mac)
        if len(octets) != 6:
            return False
        for i in octets:
            try:
                if int(i, 16) > 255:
                    return False
            except:
                return False
        return mac

    return [i.upper() for i in inputMacList if MacParser(i) != False]

macList = ["00-15-F2-20-4D-6B", "Kozel", "00:13:aa:00:00:01",
           "00:13:AA:00:tr:01", "00-01-01-20-55-55", "00-01-01-20abc-55"]

validMacList = MacValidator(macList)
```

Answer (score 0):

This Regex validates the following MAC format

```
"Ae:Bd:00:00:00:00"
"00-00-00-00-00-00"
"aaaa.bbbb.cccc"
```

```java
private static final String MAC_PATTERN = "(([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[-:.]){5}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\\.){2}[0-9A-Fa-f]{4})";

public class MacRegExp {

    private static final String MAC_PATTERN = "(([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[-:.]){5}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\\.){2}[0-9A-Fa-f]{4})";

    static boolean validateMAC(final String mac){          
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(MAC_PATTERN);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mac);
        return matcher.matches();             
    }

}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This works like a charm.

```
def isMAC48Address(inputString):
    if inputString.count(":")!=5:
        return False
    for i in inputString.split(":"):
        for j in i:
            if j>"F" or (j<"A" and not j.isdigit()) or len(i)!=2:
                return False
    return True
```

Comment: This isn't a correct answer as it is. Please edit as it's close.

Comment: @Jay Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: Well - it's closer but the OP wants 6 components, not 5. I updated your code. :-)

Comment: Hmm. Correct me if I'm wrong, but the OP wants 6 components with 5 colons, right? If that's true, then my code would return False for "00:29:15:80:4E:4A", which would be wrong, because it is a valid address (with 5 colons).

Comment: You sir, are absolutely correct. I re-wrote this in Swift and separated into components, which are 6, so I had 6 on the brain. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Just works Perfect
#validate the MAC addr

#!/usr/bin/python
import re

mac = "01-3e-4f-ee-23-af"

result = re.match(r"([0-9a-fA-F]{2}[-:]){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2}$",mac)

if result:
    print ("Correct MAC")
else:
    print ("Incorrect MAC")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pattern = "^(([0-9]{2}|[a-f]{2}|[0-9][a-f]|[a-f][0-9])\:){5}([0-9]{2}|[a-f]{2}|[0-9][a-f]|[a-f]|[0-9])$"

valid_mac_check =re.search(pattern,"00:29:15:80:4E:4A",re.IGNORECASE)
print(valid_mac_check.group())
```

Comment: While this code may be useful, generally giving **_an explanation_** would be helpful. See [answer] for more details, and then [edit] your answer to include those details.

Comment: Instead of the verbose `([0-9]{2}|[a-f]{2}|[0-9][a-f]|[a-f][0-9])`, you could simply write `[0-9a-f]{2}`

Answer (score 0):

Short way always *Good* !

```
import binascii
def checkMac(_mac):
    try:
        mac = binascii.unhexlify(_mac.replace(':',''))
        return mac
    except:
        return None
```

Hope this usefull(best regards)!