# Regex to match MAC address and also extract it's values

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to first check if a string confirms the format of a MAC address, and if it does I would like to extract all the byte values out of the string.

So far I wrote this, and it successfully matches if the format of a mac address is correct or not:

```
 mac_regx = re.compile(r'^([0-9A-F]{1,2})(\:[0-9A-F]{1,2}){5}$', re.IGNORECASE)
```

But when I use this regex to extract the byte values, I'm only getting the first and the last one:

```
(Pdb) print(mac_regx.findall('aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff'))
[('aa', ':ff')]
```

I know I could simply `split` by `:` and that would do the job. I was just hoping to be able to do both, the matching and value extraction, in only one step with one regex.

Comment: see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629643/how-do-i-validate-the-format-of-a-mac-address

Comment: @FredrikPihl thanks, but this thread only answers the matching, which is what I already have. But what I'm looking for is a pattern that can do the matching and also the extraction of the values between the `:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all the matches, you should avoid using `{5}`:

```
mac_regx = re.compile(r'^([0-9A-F]{1,2})\:([0-9A-F]{1,2})\:([0-9A-F]{1,2})\:([0-9A-F]{1,2})\:([0-9A-F]{1,2})\:([0-9A-F]{1,2})$', re.IGNORECASE)
```

or, shorter,

```
mac_regx = re.compile(r'^([0-9A-F]{1,2})' + '\:([0-9A-F]{1,2})'*5 + '$', re.IGNORECASE)
```

You could also make a list of 6 occurrences of a string `'[0-9A-F]{1,2})'` and join them with `'\:'`.

Comment: i like the idea of using the multiplier on the pattern string, instead of a regex quantifier. Thanks!

Comment: That's the solution I'm using now, works perfect: `re.compile('^' + '[\:\-]'.join(['([0-9A-F]{1,2})']*6) + '$', re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: What is the meaning of “{1,2}”?

Comment: @ItaiGanot It means that the subexpression before it happens between once and twice. So, `{1,3}` would mean "once, twice, or three times" (not just "once or three times").

Answer (score 0):

I cheated and used variation submitted by [mauro.stettler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2074467/mauro-stettler). I think this is pretty clear and straight forward one liner. `mac_validation` should return `True` or `False`. Thanks Mario!

```
import re
mac_validation = bool(re.match('^' + '[\:\-]'.join(['([0-9a-f]{2})']*6) + '$', mac_input.lower()))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different possible formats.  So it may be difficult for a single regex to handle them all.

If you are willing to use code rather than a regex, [the IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) will handle various formats at the same time.

The library will read most common formats for MAC addresses, like aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff, aa-bb-cc-dd-ee-ff, aabb.ccdd.eeff, aa bb cc dd ee ff, it supports addresses that are 48 or 64 bits, and also allows you to specify ranges of addresses like aa-ff:bb:cc:*:ee:ff

Verify if an address is valid:

```
    String str = "aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff";
    MACAddressString addrString = new MACAddressString(str);
    try {
         MACAddress addr = addrString.toAddress();
         //extract values with addr.getSegment(i).getLowerSegmentValue()
         ...
    } catch(AddressStringException e) {
        //e.getMessage provides validation issue
    }
```

Comment: The question is specifically asking about Python, this answer does not belong here