# Check Valid Mac Address from Database in Python code

Tags: python

I want to add Mac address (Validation) check before my python script runs. I there have a database online. So in the script I want to add this mac address check before runs the script.

My script have this right now

Downloading Files from My Web server

So my script wanna be like this after

Get Mac Adress from my Android Device. Then Check Mac Address is that valid or not using pre-def list (db file)

if it valid Then

Downloading files from my web server

Comment: Please add the code to better explain.

Comment: Be more clear in what you are looking for.
Check MAC address: means valid MAC address or you have a pre-defined list ?
You have to extract MAC address from the network traffic or you have the MAC address.

Comment: Mac-address auth means the script is running as a service? Accessible on a port? And will ONLY run on the LAN?

Comment: @timkofu No even on the LAN, just on the local subnet, which can be much smaller. Also the MAC address is no available directly It has to be resolved by ARP which is done differently on different operating systems.

Comment: It was running in the android. Yes I have pre-defined list. on .db file. First want to get mac address from my Android Device and then Check is that match with db file

Comment: @KlausD. Yes. But if on Linux, he can log the MACs of SYN requests to that port, and have a log parsing pipeline of some sort, extract the mac and match it to the request. A lot of frustration before it works, but it "could" work.

Comment: @Yogeesh 
It was running in the android. Yes I have pre-defined list. on .db file. First want to get mac address from my Android Device and then Check is that match with db file

Comment: @navneet35371 http://d-h.st/NCGK

Comment: @NishanthaIndika break the tasks down and solve it 1 by 1. Your Qn is very generic with almost no info. About what db etc

Comment: @YogeeshSeralathan db file have table and field named mac_address. There have list of mac addresses

Comment: [Duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7629690/1767377)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This  simple python program will help you in finding the valid mac address

```
import re

def checkMAC(x):
      if re.match("[0-9a-f]{2}([-:])[0-9a-f]{2}(\\1[0-9a-f]{2}){4}$", x.lower()):
            return 1
    else:
            return 0

print checkMAC("AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF")
print checkMAC("00-11-22-33-44-66")
print checkMAC("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c")
print checkMAC("This is not a mac")
```

It accepts 12 hex digits with either : or - as separators between pairs (but the separator must be uniform... either all separators are : or are all -).

This is the explanation:

[0-9a-f] means an hexadecimal digit

{2} means that we want two of them

[-:] means either a dash or a colon. Note that the dash as first char doesn't mean a range but only means itself. This atom is enclosed in parenthesis so it can be reused later as a back reference.

[0-9a-f]{2} is another pair of hexadecimal digits

\1 this means that we want to match the same expression that we matched before as separator. This is what guarantees uniformity. Note that the regexp syntax is \1 but I'm using a regular string so backslash must be escaped by doubling it.

[0-9a-f]{2} another pair of hex digits

{4} the previous parenthesized block must be repeated exactly 4 times, giving a total of 6 pairs of digits:    (   ) * 4

$ The string must end right after them

Comment: No no I want to check my mac address with comparing pre-def list. A db file.

Comment: Get my mac address (Android)
Check is that matching with any mac address in database.
If matching one found then script runs

Comment: Any reason for returning 1 and 0? Surely True and False would make a lot more sense?

Comment: You cloud just use the `valid_mac` function of the lovely [`netaddr`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netaddr) Python module instead of your regex magic ;)